# Replacing a string deletes first paragraph from my sample text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a small python script which creates a duplicate of a Microsoft Word file, that has two paragraphs. While duplicating it should replace a placeholder in the text with a string from a list.

Now my problem is that when I replace the placeholder with the string from my list I only get the second paragraph as an output. 
I do not understand why the first paragraph of the text gets "deleted" while replacing the word. Can you explain me why this happens?

```
from docx import Document
import re

for name in range(len(entity_name)):

    input_doc = Document(template_location)
    keyRegex = re.compile(r'xxx')

    paragraphs = []
    for para in input_doc.paragraphs:
        p = para.text
        #Check1
        print(p)
        p = keyRegex.sub(entity_name[name], p)
        #Check2
        print(p)
```

**Output at Check1:**

> This is my x1 sample.
>
> My x1 sample.

**Output at Check2:**

> My x1 sample.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is your `keyRegex` really only `xxx`?

Comment: Apparently your `keyRegex` matches the whole first line, and `entity_name[name]` (with which you're replacing it) is empty.

Comment: @AKX Right now, yes. But this should just be a simplified example. I build the code previously with „p = p.replace(old, new), but it also resulted in the same issue.